# OpenCV “already defined” error

Tags: c++, winforms, opencv, c++-cli

I am currently making a project using OpenCV in Windows Forms C++. In the first form, the  `CvCapture* capture;` is running successfully, but when I add this code in the second form, I get this error:

> error LNK2005: "struct CvCapture * capture" (?capture@@3PAUCvCapture@@A) already defined in Form2.obj
>
> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found.

The OpenCV libraries include successfully. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `CvCapture* capture;` only once.

Comment: I defined the CvCapture* capture; once in Form2 but I still got the error.